# How to set the color of php value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I like to set the color of a php variable with jQuery depending on the content of the value. So this is the code...

```
<span style="font-size: revert;" id="anart"><strong><?php echo esc_attr($phpvalue); ?></strong></span>
```

If the output of the variable is "Jackson" the font-color should be yellow, else if "David" it should be blue. How can I implement this in jQuery?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you're already using PHP, is there a reason you don't want to set the color with PHP also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Hope it will work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let $text = $('#anart strong');
  if($text.text() === 'Jackson'){
    $text.css('color','yellow');
  }
  if($text.text() === 'David'){
    $text.css('color','blue');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without jQuery, using switch case.

```
var anart = document.querySelector('#anart');

switch (anart.innerText) {
  case "Jackson":
    anart.style.color = "yellow";
    break;

  case "David":
    anart.style.color = "blue";
}
```